# How do I fix a CallableStatement issue?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc-odbc

I'm using eclipse to link with MS SQL Server to complete a task however I'm facing some issues. When ever I write the code to read from any tables from the database it shows all the data correctly meaning the connection is good but when I'm executing a stored procedure I'm facing two problem 1.) whenever I exclude a callableStatement variable that calls the execute() method no data is sent to the database 2.) Whenever I include the callable variable that calls the execute() method I get an error stating [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter type. Can you please help me to understand what is happening

```
void insertCustomer(int trn, String Ln,String fn,String mn,String dob,String email,String ms,String tel,String pa,String ma,String en,String dp,int emp)
    {
        // Declare the JDBC object.
        Connection con = null;

        try
        {
            // Establish the connection.
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dbase");
          con.setAutoCommit(false);

          CallableStatement sp = con.prepareCall("{? = call               addcustomer(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
          sp.setInt(1,trn);
          sp.setString(2,Ln);
          sp.setString(3,fn);
          sp.setString(4,mn);
          sp.setString(5,ms);
          sp.setString(6,dob);
          sp.setString(7,email);
          sp.setString(8,tel);
          sp.setString(9,pa);
          sp.setString(10,ma);
          sp.setString(11,en);
          sp.setInt(12,emp);
          sp.setString(13,dp);
          sp.execute();//this is where the problem is 
          sp.close();

        }//end of try

        catch(Exception E)
        {
         E.printStackTrace();

        }//end of catch

    }//end of insert customer
```

this is the code for the stored procedure

```
alter procedure addcustomer
    (
        @Trn                 int,
        @LName               varchar(30),
        @FName               varchar(30),
        @MName               varchar(30),
        @MStatus             varchar(20),
        @Dob                 date,
        @Email               varchar(100),
        @Telphone            varchar(20) ,
        @Permanent_addr      varchar(300),
        @mailing_addr        varchar(300), 
        @engine_num          varchar(25),
        @emp_id              int,
        @date_of_purchase    date,
        @PartO               varchar(300)

    )
    AS
    BEGIN

         Begin tran
             INSERT INTO customer 
             VALUES(@Trn, @LName,@FName,@MName,@MStatus, @Dob,@Email,@Telphone,@Permanent_addr, @mailing_addr,@PartO)

             exec addPurchase @Trn,@engine_num,@emp_id,@date_of_purchase

             IF(@@ERROR <>0)
                BEGIN
                   SELECT'An Unexpected error has occur'
                   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                   RETURN 1
                END

             COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END
```

Comment: can you show us the code of your  stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to register the output parameters. JDBC requires that they be specified before statement execution using the various `registerOutputParameter()` methods.
2. the first ? is the result of the procedure.

Try this (I assumed that `VARCHAR` is the type of output parameter ):

```
              CallableStatement sp = con.prepareCall("{? =  call   addcustomer(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
              sp.registerOutParameter(1,Types.VARCHAR); 
              sp.setInt(2,trn);
              sp.setString(3,Ln);
              sp.setString(4,fn);
              sp.setString(5,mn);
              sp.setString(6,ms);
              sp.setString(7,dob);
              sp.setString(8,email);
              sp.setString(9,tel);
              sp.setString(10,pa);
              sp.setString(11,ma);
              sp.setString(12,en);
              sp.setInt(13,emp);
              sp.setString(14,dp);
              sp.execute();
```